# Why does this code generate a CS1525 ("invalid expression") compiler error?

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to make a program that, when a button is pressed, takes the words typed in the text box and adds it to a text file. This is what I have so far:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, string());
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, string());
}
```

The String keeps coming up with error code CS1525 ("invalid expression"). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What `string()` is supposed to do?

Comment: /the code you given in textBox2_TextChanged. as per your scenario, you need to put this code in button click

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the `string` from the `TextBox.Text` property

for example

```
 File.WriteAllText(path, textBox1.Text);
```

or

```
 File.WriteAllText(path, (sender as TextBox).Text);
```

And it sounds like you want to create a `Button` and assign a `Click` event and use that to save the `Text` from the `TextBox` to the file, and for that `AppendAllText` may be a better option.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.AppendAllText(path, textBox1.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("abc.txt"))
{
    sw1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
}
```

or

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   File.WriteAllText(path,textBox1.Text);
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(path,textBox2.Text);
}
```

Comment: The question asks what's wrong. This answer doesn't address that. At the very least, I'd expect an answer to explain what the invalid expression is and why.

Comment: @RobKennedy:- Sir I am getting your point but string() is something even I am not getting. What OP is looking after can be achieved through textBox.text property!!! :) P.S. Please correct me if I am wrong!!

Comment: When it writes to the txt file, it overwrites what was already there.  How can the new input be added on another line?

Comment: Writeline() will add the input to the next line. So its better to use WriteLine() in your case!!!